# Loop space and $K$-theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory

How can I proove without using Yoneda's lemma that $$ \Omega^2(BU \times \mathbb{Z}) \cong BU \times \mathbb{Z} ?$$
In particular how can I define a cellular map 
$$ f: \Omega^2(BU \times \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow BU \times \mathbb{Z} $$
sucht that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: For the second question to make sense, you need to specify a cell structure on both $BU$ and on $\Omega^2 (BU)$ (note that the factor of $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't affect the based loop space).  I don't think you're likely to find canonical CW structures on these spaces.  I'm not even sure they're homeomorphic to CW complexes.  They are certainly homotopy equivalent to CW complexes, although this is not obvious, especially for the loop space.  There are several ways to show that a colimit like $BU$ is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex; for the loop space, you need an old theorem of Milnor.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the first question, really.  You're asking how to prove Bott Periodicity without the Yoneda Lemma.  What proofs of Bott Periodicity do you know?  There are many, and they all involve significantly deeper mathematics than the Yoneda Lemma.

Comment: @DanRamras I ask if it is possible to prove that $\Omega^2(BU \times \mathbb{Z}) \simeq BU \times \mathbb{Z}$, defining a cellular map and then prove the equivalence...

Comment: @ArthurStuart Forse stai pensando al "Bott map"? Vedi la prima risposta: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8800/proofs-of-bott-periodicity

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yoneda's lemma and $K$-theory.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443359/yonedas-lemma-and-k-theory)